# Getting error Multiple-step operation generated error

Tags: vba, vbscript, asp-classic

I am debugging some old code and I am getting error on this part

```
    rs("country code").value = NullIfBlank(Request.Form("country code"))
```

The error says "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."

I tried to understand what NullIfBlank means and to my understanding, I tried to rewrite the code this way:

```
    If rs("country code").value Is Nothing Then
        rs("country code").value = Request.Form("country code")
    End If
```

now I am not getting an error when there is a value in rs("country code").value, but I get an error in this statement

```
    rs("country code").value = Request.Form("country code")
```

My whole code looks like this

```
    if request.form("submit")="Save Changes " or request.form("submit")="Save Changes to a New " then%>
<%
id = request.form("id")
if id is nothing then id = ""
cmd1.ActiveConnection  = strconn
cmd1.CommandText = "FormBlankSpecial"
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd1.Parameters.Append (cmd.CreateParameter("@id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, id))
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockPessimistic
rs.open (cmd1)
if cmd1.Parameters.count > 0 then
    cmd1.Parameters.delete("@id")
end if

if request.form("submit")="Save Changes to a New" then
    rs.addnew
    rsmax.open ("FormBlankMax", strconn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdStoredProc)
    rs("idx").value=(1*zeroif(rsmax("maxid").value))+1
end if

    '  rs("country code").value = NullIfBlank(Request.Form("country code"))
' I keep getting error here
    If rs("country code").value Is Nothing Then
        rs("country code").value = Request.Form("country code")
    End If
```

Below is the isnull function

```
     Public Shared Function NullIfBlank(ByVal Str)
        On Error Resume Next
        NullIfBlank = ""
        If Str = "" Then NullIfBlank = DBNull.Value Else NullIfBlank = Str
        Return NullIfBlank
    End Function
```

and the sql stored procedure looks like this

select isnull([Country Code], '') as [Country Code]
from testTable

when I do like this in sql statement

select [Country Code] as [Country Code]
from testTable

then I don't get that error.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like type mismatch. What is the exact type of the field "country code" in your database?

Comment: Hmmm.. and if you try `rs("country code") = "test"` does it work?

Comment: rs("country code") = "test" doesn't work, but I checked the type of the field in the database, it is varcahr(50). The problem is the existing code started working when the changed the stored proc from isnull(country code,'') to just country code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand:

1. `Nothing` is a special object that indicates that a variable that should contain an object does *not*. While that seems similar to n/Null pointers/references in other languages, you should not think "Null" when stumbling upon "Nothing".
2. Assigning an object (even this Nothing) to a variable needs `Set` in VBScript.
3. Null in VBScript is a special value that indicates that a variable that should contain a value does *not*. This is like Null in SQL.
4. (There is another special value to indicate not quite decent variable content in VBScript: Empty - it differs from Null in operations/comparisons.)
5. Assigning a value to a variable is done without `Set` in VBScript.

Vour:

```
id = request.form("id") 
if id is nothing then id = ""
```

seems to read a string value from a form element into `id`. Then `id` is not an object and can not be compared to the Nothing object. Or you want to access the element/object - then you must use

```
Set id = request.form("id")
```

Your

```
If rs("country code").value Is Nothing Then
```

tries to check a database column value (probably a string) to the Nothing object. Depending on your column definition the field may contain Null - then you must check for Null (**not** Nothing):

```
If IsNull( rs("country code").value) Then
```

You should publish the `NullIfBlank()` function, because "Multiple Step" errors often point to SQL problems.

Comment: I made the changes to the above code. Also, included the NullIfBalnk() function